# String comparing in python

Tags: python

I have an array of strings like

```
urls_parts=['week', 'weeklytop', 'week/day']
```

And i need to monitor inclusion of this strings in my url, so this example needs to be triggered by weeklytop part only:

```
url='www.mysite.com/weeklytop/2'
for part in urls_parts:
    if part in url:
       print part
```

But it is of course triggered by 'week' too.
What is the way to do it right?

OOps, let me specify my question a bit.
I need that code not to trigger when url='www.mysite.com/week/day/2' and part='week'
The only url needed to trigger on is when the part='week' and the url='www.mysite.com/week/2' or 'www.mysite.com/week/2-second' for example

Comment: Parse the URL using urllib.urlparse(), split the traversal into parts and then compare string by string. Is this homework?

Comment: There is pattern "week" in every one in your `url_parts` and how could you expect the computer can tell apart without tokenizing `url`?
You need to at least define word boundary before you can match in your way above...or do it regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
import re
urls_parts=['week', 'weeklytop', 'week/day']
urls_parts = sorted(urls_parts, key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
rexes = [re.compile(r'{part}\b'.format(part=part)) for part in urls_parts]

urls = ['www.mysite.com/weeklytop/2', 'www.mysite.com/week/day/2', 'www.mysite.com/week/4']
for url in urls:
    for i, rex in enumerate(rexes):
        if rex.search(url):
            print url
            print urls_parts[i]
            print
            break
```

**OUTPUT**

```
www.mysite.com/weeklytop/2
weeklytop

www.mysite.com/week/day/2
week/day

www.mysite.com/week/4
week
```

Suggestion to sort by length came from @Roman

Answer (score 3):

Sort you list by `len` and `break` from the loop at first match.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
>>> print(re.findall('\\weeklytop\\b', 'www.mysite.com/weeklytop/2'))
['weeklytop']
>>> print(re.findall('\\week\\b', 'www.mysite.com/weeklytop/2'))
[]
```

program:

```
>>> urls_parts=['week', 'weeklytop', 'week/day']
>>> url='www.mysite.com/weeklytop/2'
>>> for parts in urls_parts:
    if re.findall('\\'+parts +r'\b', url):
        print (parts)
```

output:

```
weeklytop
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use urls_parts like this?

```
 ['/week/', '/weeklytop/', '/week/day/']
```

Comment: i use this, it was just an example

Answer (score -1):

A slight change in your code would solve this issue -

```
>>> for part in urls_parts:
        if part in url.split('/'):              #splitting the url string with '/' as delimiter
            print part

    weeklytop
```

Comment: It was not me, but for example the `'week/day'` can never be found this way.